# Ubuntu Apache2 Nginx php7.0 wordpress, php file load instead of processing

Tags: server, apache2, php

That is a vanilla install, all modules are here and running. The website run correctly (http://www.shadowimoth.com/) but when I try to log into the admin panel (wordpress), the browser only give the option of downloading the file (wp-login.php) instead of serving it.

After 48 hours of verifying my various conf, changing back and forth some values (short_open_tag = Off then short_open_tag = On) I am hitting a wall.

I discard Nginx to be problem as it is only a reverse proxy (no reference to php into the conf files) and all pages that are cached are served correctly. The problem is with only pages having .php:

mysite/ work fine
mysite/index.php does not work.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

IMPORTANT :

http://serverIP/phpmyadmin/import.php odes not download, but it is served.

Comment: Can you show your nginx.conf

Comment: What part of it? nothin related to php into it

Comment: Your /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file

Comment: not have that folder or file

Comment: /etc/nginx/ does have an nginx.conf (too lost to be cut and past here), and the folder conf.d :

Comment: 01_caching_pool.conf
172.31.14.129.conf
phpmyadmin.inc
phppgadmin.inc
status.conf
vesta.conf
webmail.inc

Comment: Is there a line starting with location ~ \.php$ {

Comment: no, not in the main nginx.con, not in the secondary conf that are in the virtual host! That is why I believe the problem is apache (Nginx should be considered only as a reverse proxy in that case, I not use it as webserver).

Comment: After installing php, did you restart apache?

Comment: yes, I did. Several times as I did tinkered with several conf files (php.ini, http.conf, nginx.conf).

Comment: things are :mysite.com is working well, mysite.com/mycategory/mypage is working qell too (that is wordpress), but mysite.com/wp-admin give a download (because it explicitlly call for wp-loggin.php). Php is by so processed, but it is the extension .php that is not understood.

Comment: at least it is my understanding of the problem, but enable to find where to fix that problem.

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: 7.0, module are enabled, conf are enabled. It is not a basic user problem, It is a configuration problem.

Comment: Have you installed libapache2-mod-php7.0?